# WARN: ArgumentError: missing keyword: user_id in job perform method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, sidekiq, shopify-app, rails-activejob

I am trying to pass devise current_user into rails job with Sidekiq Shopify worker, but the job initiates, I get  `WARN: ArgumentError: missing keyword: user_id`. Here is what I have done below which could be that I am doing it wrongly.

**OrderWebhookController**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class OrderWebhooksController < ApplicationController
  include ShopifyApp::WebhookVerification

  def orders_paid
    params.permit!
    OrdersPaidJob.perform(shop_domain: shop_domain, webhook: webhook_params.to_h, user_id: current_user.id)
    head :no_content
  end

  private

  def webhook_params
    params.except(:controller, :action, :type)
  end
end
```

**OrdersPaidJob**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class OrdersPaidJob < ApplicationJob

  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:, user_id:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)

    webhook.to_json

    shop.with_shopify_session do
      customer = webhook['customer']

      payload = {
        user_id: user_id,
        email: customer['email'],
        amount_spent: customer['total_spent'],
        first_name: customer['first_name'],
        last_name: customer['last_name'],
        point_balance: (customer['total_spent']),
        recorded_on: Time.now
      }

      customer_records = [].tap do |array|
        array << payload
      end

      customer_exists(customer) ? CustomerDetail.upsert(customer_records) : CustomerDetail.insert_all(customer_records)
    end
  end

  private

  def earning_rules
    EarningRule.order_rule || 0
  end

  def customer_exists(customer)
    CustomerDetail.find_by_email(customer['email'])
  end
end
```

**Log Error**

```
error_message\":\"missing keyword: user_id\",\"error_class\":\"ArgumentError\",\"failed_at\":1574158701.8283021,\"retry_count\":4,\"retried_at\":1574159903.266159}"}
2019-11-19T10:39:09.892Z pid=6341 tid=oxrqw3mjx WARN: ArgumentError: missing keyword: user_id
2019-11-19T10:39:09.893Z pid=6341 tid=oxrqw3mjx WARN: /Users/tiwa/RubymineProjects/ShopifyLoyaltyApp/app/jobs/orders_paid_job.rb:5:in `perform'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activejob-6.0.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:39:in `block in perform_now'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:112:in `block in run_callbacks'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/i18n-1.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:297:in `with_locale'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activejob-6.0.1/lib/active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `instance_exec'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:66:in `use_zone'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activejob-6.0.1/lib/active_job/timezones.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Timezones>'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `instance_exec'
/Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can access this passed arguments as follow:

```
  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:, user_id:)
```

change to:

```
  def perform(params)
```

and then `params["user_id"]` etc.

Sidekiq does not support named parameters https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple

However, there are some good workarounds on this like this one: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2372#issuecomment-469660538

This is copypasta from above source:

```
# jobs/job.rb
class Job
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  # ... more default options here

  def perform(params={})
    params = params.to_h.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
    execute params
  end
end

# jobs/greet_job.rb
class Greet < Job
  def execute(name: "there")
    puts "Hi #{name}!"
  end
end
So now all jobs simply define execute instead of defining perform.

And it even works nicely in specs:

# spec/greet_job_spec.rb
expect(Greet).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job(name: "Lloyd Christmas")
```

Comment: But it the arguments work if I remove `user_id:`. The problem is just that I need `current_user` in the hash I am saving to db, and that is why I added `user_id:` as an argument.